# shutil.copyfile keep returning error of permission denied

Tags: python, shutil, ioerror

I am trying to copy contents of a folder but it keeps on showing the error of Permission denied.

```
 import subprocess
 import shutil
 import os


 procId = subprocess.call('adb pull /sdcard/HDrec2.0/records/ tmp/', stdin = subprocess.PIPE)
folderPath = (os.getcwd() + os.sep + 'tmp')
shutil.copyfile(folderPath ,'D:\job\HDrec2_MotoG\Windows\records')
```

error message is

```
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\job\HDrec2_MotoG\Windows\z2.py", line 20, in <module>
    shutil.copyfile(folderPath ,'D:\job\HDrec2_MotoG\Windows\records')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 96, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:\\job\\HDrec2_MotoG\\Windows\\tmp'
```

Comment: Looks like you don't have permission to the write to that folder.

Comment: Have u try run the script as admin ?

Comment: yeah, I did run it as administrator but the problem was with the command

Answer (score 0):

yeah, I did run it as administrator but the problem was with the command ...  shutil.copy won't work due to some reason so I used the following command to copy

`distutils.dir_util.copy_tree(folderPath,r'D:/job/HDrec2_MotoG/Windows/records')`

and this worked somehow :D